# Java JNI for basic java.util operations

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I found out, that many operations in java.util.concurrent or java.lang perform native method calls.

For example native `compareAndSwapInt()` from `sun.misc.Unsafe` may be called extensively in highload concurrent apps.

JNI calls are considered much slower than java method calls, **can not be inlined or optimized by JIT** and such calls have their own stack. Am I wrong and such calls are optimized in any way? Or JNI call overhead is much smaller, than jobs that it performs (consider `compareAndSwapInt()` example)?

Generally, I'm going to implement membars with JNI (more nice looking, than volatile r/w). Is it a good idea to implement them via JNI? If not, than how to do it in more optimal way?

Comment: Google for "JVM intrinsics"

Comment: @kdgregory So, these native methods are not JNI calls and they are handled directly by JIT. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are welcome to create an answer for upvotes and documentation.

Comment: :shrug: a real answer would take time that I don't really have, and wouldn't be nearly as good as the slideshare deck that turns up first in the Gooole results.